# MySQL date/time calculation

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a `date` and `time` column in my mysql table called `start_date` and `start_time` respectively. I want my users the ability to set reminders for themselves to be sent X hours before `start_time`, min. 1 hour and max 24 hours.

I'll be running a CRON script to send these reminders. Right now I do:

```
SELECT * FROM auctions WHERE start_date=CURDATE() AND status='0'
```

To get all the auctions that will be starting today and haven't yet started. My question is, how can I figure out if the time now is `X` hours before `start_time` so I can send them a reminder if it is.

Any suggestions at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
FROM records 
WHERE (records.startDate BETWEEN NOW() AND ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 HOUR)) 
AND (records.status = '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there some reason why you can't just use a simple timestamp field instead of one for date and one for time.  That way you could find all the ones that start in the next 5 hours (say), by doing

```sql
select * from auctions where start_ts between now() and now() + interval '5 hours';
```

Note: the interval syntax varies slightly between databases, and that's the one for postgresql, so you might have to change it slightly for mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I actually did it this way before all the answers were sent and its working. Because i'm on a deadline I can't go back and change it :)

```php
$sql="SELECT HOUR(ADDTIME(CURTIME(),'$hour')) as remindHour, HOUR(CURTIME()) as curHour";
$result=$this->db->query($sql);

extract($result->getAllSingle());

if ($remindHour <=$curHour) {
    // Send reminders
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use unixtime to save the time?

Since PHP has a wonderful function called [strtotime](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Within in you can say. strtotime("+20 hours") and get the unixtime for 20 hours from now.

Then its just a matter of which field is larger than the other, if so, send the notification.

Comment: Why would you assume he's running PHP? To start with, he will be using a cronjob, that's one indication that it might not be PHP. second, why would you need to use strtotime to calculate 20 hours in seconds? That's basic math...

Comment: why would a cronjob indicate that it's not PHP?